# spring boot swagger ui not showing

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

this is what I am seeing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AayTx.png)

my SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
@ComponentScan("pollingDemo")
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig        springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new     SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .includePatterns("/api/.*");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("Demo APIs", "APIs for Demo",
                "http://www.jemrug.com",
                "donotuse@donotuse",
                "© MIT Copyright",     "http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php");

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

My Controller has the following annotations:-

```
@Api(basePath = "api", value = "/Hello", description = "Operations with     person", produces = "application/json")
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    @ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Say Hello To World     greeting using Swagger",notes ="hello")
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name",      defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Arrrrgh Help someone please

Regards,

Jemrug

Comment: What's your spring-boot and swagger version?

Comment: spring boot version is ::: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

Comment: spring boot version is ::: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)  swagger is <swagger.ui.version>1.0.1</swagger.ui.version> not using springfox anywhere. I think its swagger-springmvc-1.0.2.jar.  I am trying do auto endpoint discovery rather than use anotaions. Thanks

Comment: Its swagger 1.2